# How to read a static file on deployment on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I want to be able to deploy my spring boot application onlne on heroku. My app loads data from a static .json file which is located on my resources folder.

[image]

So far I've tried this code but it doesn't work. For some reason I can't read the data from the json file.

```
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
       File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("static/data/data.json").getFile());
       JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()));
       List<Category> allCategories = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Category>>(){}.getType());

       return allCategories;
    }
```

Comment: is there any exception ? whats the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data.json` is moved inside JAR which is deployed on heroku, try using `getResourceAsStream(path)` instead `getResource()`. pseudocode could be,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("static/data/data.json");
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
List<Category> allCategories = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Category>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you move data folder directly under resources as static resources path might be conflict here and use below should work.

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("data/data.json").getFile());
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `getFile()` may produce NPE

Answer (score 0):

If it's a spring project, files present in resources folder gets copied to `target/classes` folder on mvn build. So to use it, do following:

```
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

ResourceUtils.getURL("classpath:static/data/data.json")
```